# Doc2Vec Distributed Memory Model of Paragraph Vectors (PV-DM) doesn't classified

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, embedding, doc2vec

I'm using Keras to code DM according to Mikolov article.

The documents we are facing are very particular : we have a lot of different documents (around 20 000) but very few different words (only 100).

When I use the document embedding in order to classify my documents, it doesn't seem to work ...

I don't know if this is due to the very specific data or to my way to code DM.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated !

This is my code :

```
## Libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Lambda,concatenate, Input, Flatten
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras import optimizers
from keras.constraints import non_neg
import random as rd


## Parameters

seuil = 0.0001 # Mikolov threshold
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
dim=20 # dimension of words and documents embeddings
lr = 0.005 # learning rate
epochs = 15
shuffle=True
steps_per_epoch = 10000
window_size = 7
seed=123
rd.seed(seed)

V1 = 100 # number of words
V2 = 20000 # number of documents
```

This what my corpus looks like :

```
new_corpus =
[[2],
 [33, 33, 11],
 [8, 16],
 [27, 10],
 [13],
 [],
 [21, 21, 32, 10, 1],
 [],
 [1, 27],
 ... ]
```

The neural network used :

```
input_words=Input((window_size*2,))
cbow_words = Embedding(input_dim=V1, output_dim=dim, input_length=window_size*2 ,embeddings_constraint=non_neg())(input_words)

input_texts=Input((V2,))
cbow_texts = Embedding(input_dim=V2, output_dim=dim, input_length=V2 ,embeddings_constraint=non_neg())(input_texts)

concat = concatenate([cbow_words,cbow_texts],axis=1)
lambd = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1), output_shape=(dim,))(concat)
output = Dense(V1+1, activation='softmax')(lambd) # V1+1 because words are indexed from 1

cbow = Model(inputs=[input_words,input_texts], outputs=output)

cbow.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(lr=lr, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0))
cbow.summary()
```

It prints :

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_47 (InputLayer)           (None, 14)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_48 (InputLayer)           (None, 20000)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_47 (Embedding)        (None, 14, 20)       2160        input_47[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_48 (Embedding)        (None, 20000, 20)    400000      input_48[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_24 (Concatenate)    (None, 20000, 20)    0           embedding_47[0][0]               
                                                                 embedding_48[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_24 (Lambda)              (None, 20)           0           concatenate_24[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)                (None, 101)          2121        lambda_24[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
```

This is the way the data is transformed into a genetator :

```
generatedData=generate_data(new_corpus, window_size, V1)

for x, y in generatedData:
    print(x,y)
```

Fisrt element represents the context.

Second element represents the id of the document with a one hot vector.

Third element represents the predicted word as a one hot vector.

These are two first lines

```
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4]]), array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)] [[... 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 23]]), array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)] [[... 0. 0. 1. .... 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
...
```

Then I fit the model :

```
cbow.fit_generator(generatedData,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,shuffle=shuffle)
```

The model converges.

```
E1=pd.DataFrame(cbow.layers[2].get_weights()[0]) # words embedding
E2=pd.DataFrame(cbow.layers[3].get_weights()[0]) # docs embedding
```

Documents are ultimately classified as random ...

Comment: Sorry, it's Distributed Memory Model of Paragraph Vectors (PV-DM) according to Mikolov (https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf)

Comment: What kind of classification, into how many classes, are you attempting? What do other models, such as something based on scikit-learn's `TfidfVectorizer` & then some classifier(s), achieve on evaluation metrics compared to your Keras-PV-DM approach? Typical uses of PV-DM on natural language have much larger vocabularies, so that may be a factor – but if your classification results are truly "random" there may be other problems in your setup or (not shown) evaluation.

Comment: Is your real aim to perform a classification, rather than to learn Keras or learn how to make your own PV-DM implementation? If so, you might want to use an off-the-shelf working PV-DM implementation, such as `Doc2Vec` in `gensim`. (Even if you are trying to learn Keras/your-own-implementation-skills, you might want to use a proven library in parallel, as a comparative baseline, to know if this algorithm is helpful on your data or not, and what ranges of evaluation scores are realistic.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My real aim is to classify documents using PV-DM. I did it using gensim but in gensim, it's impossible to check if the model has converged ...

Comment: Gensim seems to have classified well so I think the issue comes from my code